# iOS Downloader App and Ecommerce Package?

Tags: ios, e-commerce

I'm having to launch an ecommerce store that sells audiobooks, and one of my top goals is to make it more mobile friendly. The actual purchase portion isn't a problem, but since iOS doesn't allow in-browser downloads of audio files, I'm looking at having to provide an app for that purpose.

Is there a packaged ecommerce/downloader solution that I could use, such that rather than designing an app from scratch for my store I can build the store using the ecommerce solution and do some configuration to the app to link them up? The only real requirement is that people be able to sign into their accounts, and play/download any files they have bought.

If not, are there any open-source core downloader iOS apps I could use as a base to design my own downloader? I've tried my google-fu, but any query that involves "iOS" and "download" just results in a million "how do I download my app?" FAQs from across the internet.

(I'm not concerned about Android as much since they can just download the audio files, though if the solution supports apps for both so much the better.)